# Is there a variable I can use to call a senders name?

Tags: gmail, google-apps-script, gmail-canned-response

I built a script for auto replying...

```
function autoReply() {
  var interval = 5;        //  if the script runs every 5 minutes; change otherwise
  var daysOff = [6,0];   // 1=Mo, 2=Tu, 3=We, 4=Th, 5=Fr, 6=Sa, 0=Su
 var date = new Date();    
 var day = date.getDay();    
 // get the current hour    
 var currenthour = date.getHours();    
 // define the work-hours start and end hours    
 var starthour= 7;    
 var endhour = 17; 
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("autoresponded");
if ((daysOff.indexOf(day) !=-1) ||(daysOff.indexOf(day) ==-1 && !(currenthour >=starthour && currenthour <=endhour))) {
    var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
    var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox label:myfilteringlabel !label:autoresponded after:' + timeFrom);
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      var message = threads[i].getMessages()[0];
      if (message.getFrom().indexOf("myemail@gmail.com") < 0 && message.getFrom().indexOf("no-repl") < 0 && message.getFrom().indexOf("bounce") < 0 && message.getFrom().indexOf("spam") < 0) {
        threads[i].reply("", {htmlBody: "<p>blah blah</p>", from: 'user@email.com', name: 'User'});}
          
        label.addToThread(threads[i]);
      }
    }
  }
```

Can anyone tell me how I might insert the senders "FROM" name into the body? Is there a variable I can call here?

Note: I'm aware this may not always accurately portray their name btw.

**Edit:** `getFrom()` is great, but I'd love to pull only the given name.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. What is the problem with `getFrom()`?

Comment: Just to clarify... `getFrom()` might, for the sake of discussion, return a string that looks something like this:   "Fred Smith <FredSmith@hotmail.com>" . Is it the case that you are trying to extract the words  "Fred Smith" and then use them in the body?

Comment: getFrom() is handy but i'd really like to extract the first name only. So to use the above example I'd love to insert "Fred"

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might suit. Insert the appropriate code inside your thread loop.

This example uses `SPLIT`, `RegExp` and `substring()` [refer: StackOverflow examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17573904/1330560).

The code does not include any error checking though this is, I would suggest, essential for a production system.

---

```
var thename = themessage.getFrom();
// Logger.log("DEBUG: The message is from:"+thename); // Log from address of the message

// REGEX
var regExp = new RegExp(".+?(?=<)", "gi"); // "i" is for case insensitive
// Logger.log("REGEX: the sender is "+regExp.exec(thename)[0]); 
// END REGEX

// SUBSTRING
var namelen = thename.length;  
// Logger.log("DEBUG: getfrom result has a length of "+namelen); 
var firstarrow = thename.indexOf("<");
// Logger.log("DEBUG: the first arrow occurs at "+firstarrow);
// Logger.log("SUBSTRING: the sender is "+thename.substring(0, firstarrow-1))
// END SUBSTRING


//SPLIT
var sender = thename.split("<")[0];
// Logger.log("SPLIT: the sender is "+sender); 
// END SPLIT
```